# Internalframe size is not always maximized ( alternating)

Tags: java, swing

I am facing a weird issue that I can't see to understand why. I have a frame with an Internal JFrame that opens upon  a menu click. This internal frame is supposed to be always maximized. When I run the program and click on the menu then it does what is expected. If I close the internal jframe and click the button again, the internal jframe is minimized. If I close it and click the button then it is maximimzed!! Why is it alternating like that. Here is the code that open the internal jframe. This method is inside the JFrame class

```
 private void onButtonClick(){
        InternalFrameProp intFrame = new InternalFrameProp ();     
        intFrame.setVisible(true);
        jDesktopPane1.add(intFrame );
        try {
            intFrame .setMaximum(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainHomePage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,   null, ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: An animated example will be good.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

As  I was trying to  put a runnable example, I noticed that this behaviour only happen in the Windows look and feel. To get around I did

```
jDesktopPane1.setDesktopManager(new DefaultDesktopManager());
```

That seemed to fix the problem! I have no idea why but it worked!